# calling url parameters in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, url-parameters

I have the below function call that needs to pass url parameters to the php file.  How would I go about passing these using the $_GET function. Below is what I have, obviously not working. THanks.

```
$.ajax({   type: "POST",   url: '"chkinpost.php + "?eventid=<php echo $_GET['eventid']?> +  ?eventname= <php echo $_GET['eventid']?>"' });
```

Comment: You have two question marks in your URL for one. And your quotes are all screwed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chkinpost.php?eventid=<?php echo $_GET['eventid']; ?>&eventname=<?php echo $_GET['eventname']; ?>"
});
```

Although I'm not entirely sure why you're using a POST to pass GET params, that would at least be how the formatting and correct syntax would look. Also, I changed the second variable being taken from the PHP to eventname, since I doubt you meant to pass the eventid as both the id and the name.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.ajax({   type: "POST",   url: '"chkinpost.php + "?eventid=<? echo $_GET['eventid']?> +  ?
eventname= <? echo $_GET['eventid']?>"' });
```